# How reduce the complexity of the searching in two lists algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to find some common items in two lists. I **cannot sort** it, order is important. Have to find how many elements from `secondList` occur in `firstList`. Now it looks like below:

```
int[] firstList;
int[] secondList;
int iterator=0;
for(int i:firstList){
 while(i <= secondList[iterator]/* two conditions more */){
       iterator++;
       //some actions
   }
}
```

Complexity of this algorithm is **n x n**. I try to reduce the complexity of this operation, but I don't know how compare elements in different way? Any advice?

**EDIT:**
Example: `A=5,4,3,2,3` `B=1,2,3`
We look for pairs `B[i],A[j]`
Condition: 
when

```
B[i] < A[j]
         j++
```

when

```
B[i] >= A[j]
         return B[i],A[j-1]
```

next iteration through the list of **A** to an element **j-1** (mean `for(int z=0;z<j-1;z++)`)
*I'm not sure, Did I make myself clear?*
**Duplicated are allowed.**

Comment: What's the possible max size of the list?

Comment: Can you give an example? This is not clear: "Have to find how many elements from secondList occur in firstList." <-- does that include duplicates? How should it behave if first is { 1, 4, 3, 4 } and second is { 4, 4 }?

Comment: If you don't intend to involve O(n) storage, then you can't theoretically solve this better than O(n^2).

Comment: can you explain me one thing, you are looking for how many elements from one list occur in second one, why in this case order is important?

Comment: @Swapnil
Max size is not greater than 2^20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be  - put all the elements from the first array in a `HashSet` and then do an iteration over the second array. This reduces the complexity to the sum of the lengths of the two arrays. It has the downside of taking additional memory, but unless you use more memory I don't think you can improve your brute force solution.

EDIT: to avoid further dispute on the matter. If you are allowed to have duplicates in the first array and you actually care how many times does an element in the second array match an array in the first one, use `HashMultiSet`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `HashSet` will swallow duplicates

Comment: @fge you only care if an element appears in both arrays not how many times!

Comment: @fge I don't agree, he says `common items in two` this implies he does not care "how many times" they are common

Comment: @fge If you want a result that is a function of the indices in both arrays, then you cannot have it in less that O(nxn)

Comment: @ignis not true - use same approach and `HashMap` or `HashMultiMap`, depending on the statement's reading

Comment: Oh, and there is another flaw in the way you do this: `HashSet` does not respect order. OP cannot change order.

Comment: Another awkward edge-case, if there are dupes in the second array and you *don't* care how many times a match is duplicated, then by running over the second list you double-count the matches. The fix is to remove each element from the set the first time you count it, or to compute two sets (one for each list) and intersect them.

Comment: @all please lets take this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22736/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-14335386-how-reduce-the-complexity-of-the-sear)

Answer (score 3):

- Put all the items of the first list in a set
- For each item of the second list, test if its in the set.

Solved in less than n x n !

**Edit to please fge :)**

Instead of a set, you can use a map with the item as key and the number of occurrence as value.

Then for each item of the second list, if it exists in the map, execute your action once per occurence in the first list (dictionary entries' value).

Comment: A `Set` swallows duplicates, the OP didn't say if dups were possible

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of sense ! If OP wants dups between two lists, we don't care about dups within one of the two lists, do we ?

Comment: Well yes we do: this means the operation may have to be done twice, not once.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*; 

int[] firstList;
int[] secondList;
int iterator=0;   

HashSet hs = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(firstList));
HashSet result = new HashSet();

while(i <= secondList.length){
  if (hs.contains( secondList[iterator]))  
  {
    result.add(secondList[iterator]);
  }   
 iterator++;
 }
```

result will contain required common element.
Algorithm complexity n

Answer (score 1):

Just because the order is important doesn't mean that you cannot sort either list (or both). It only means you will have to copy first before you can sort anything. Of course, copying requires additional memory and sorting requires additional processing time... yet I guess all solutions that are better than O(n^2) will require additional memory and processing time (also true for the suggested HashSet solutions - adding all values to a HashSet costs additional memory and processing time).

Sorting both lists is possible in O(n * log n) time, finding common elements once the lists are sorted is possible in O(n) time. Whether it will be faster than your native O(n^2) approach depends on the size of the lists. In the end only testing different approaches can tell you which approach is fastest (and those tests should use realistic list sizes as to be expected in your final code).

The Big-O notation is no notation that tells you anything about *absolute speed*, it only tells you something about *relative speed*. E.g. if you have two algorithms to calculate a value from an input set of elements, one is O(1) and the other one is O(n), this doesn't mean that the O(1) solution is always faster. This is a big misconception of the Big-O notation! It only means that if the number of input elements doubles, the O(1) solution will still take approx. the same amount of time while the O(n) solution will take approx. twice as much time as before. So there is no doubt that by constantly increasing the number of input elements, there must be a point where the O(1) solution will become faster than the O(n) solution, yet for a very small set of elements, the O(1) solution may in fact be slower than the O(n) solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this solution will work *if there are no duplicates in either the first or second array*. As the question does not tell, we cannot be sure.

First, build a `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` out of the first array, and a `HashSet<Integer>` out of the second array.

Second, retain in the first set only elements that are in the second set.

Third, iterate over the first set and proceed:

```
// A LinkedHashSet retains insertion order
Set<Integer> first = LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(firstArray));
// A HashSet does not but we don't care
Set<Integer> second = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(secondArray));

// Retain in first only what is in second
first.retainAll(second);

// Iterate

for (int i: first)
    doSomething();
```